# How to Loop through with Beautiful Soup to put table text in a data frame (Python)

Tags: dataframe, loops, beautifulsoup

Here is the link to the page I am trying to scrape from: https://churchdwight.com/ingredient-disclosure/antiperspirant-deodorant/40002569-ultramax-clear-gel-cool-blast.aspx

Here is my code:

'''
#Scraping a Data Table from the CHD Website
#Load CHD Website HTML code
result = requests.get(current_url, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})

```
#Check and see if the page successfully loaded
result_status = result.status_code
                      
if result.status_code == 200:
                      
    #Extract the HTML code and pass it through beautiful soup
    source = result.content
    document = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    #Since each page has one table for each product, we can use the table attribute to find the table
    check = 0
    table = document.find("table")
    
    while check <= 0:
        
        #Check to make sure that you got the right table by checking whether the text within the first header title is 'INGREDIENT'
        if table.find("span").get_text() == "INGREDIENT NAME":
            check += 1
        else:
            table = table.find_next("table")
            

    #Since HTML uses tr for rows, we can use find all to get our rows
    rows = table.find_all('span', style ='font-size:13px;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;')
        
    
    #Loop through the rows
    for row in rows[3:]:
        bar = row.find('span', style ='font-size:13px;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;')
        bar_text = row.get_text(strip = True)
        cells_names.append(bar_text)
        
    
    data_pandas = pd.DataFrame(cells_names, columns = ['Ingredients'])
    return data_pandas
   

else:
    #Print out an error if the result status is not 200
    print("Status error" + "  " + str(result_status) + "has occurred!")
```

'''

I am getting missing the lubricant/emulsifer in my data frame and I think it is because the span style has an extra bit saying color:black;background:white

Any help would be much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only `pandas` to grab table data

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_html('https://churchdwight.com/ingredient-disclosure/antiperspirant-deodorant/40002569-ultramax-clear-gel-cool-blast.aspx')[2]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
0                            INGREDIENT NAME                            FUNCTION
1                                      Water                             Solvent
2                         Cyclopentasiloxane                Lubricant/emulsifier
3                              SD Alcohol 40                        Drying agent
4                           Propylene glycol                           Humectant
5                                Dimethicone                     Skin protectant
6                  PEG/PPG-18/18 dimethicone                          Emulsifier
7           Sodium bicarbonate (baking soda)                          Deodorizer
8                                  Fragrance                           Fragrance
9  Aluminium zirconium tetrachlorohydrex gly  Active ingredient - antiperspirant
```